# Does anybody know any specifics about Torqasm Rao or Torqasm Vo?

Tags: dc, superman

These are both mental (as in psychic) and physical martial arts made on Krypton, currently the only two martial disciplines we have any info on from Superman's home world.

One deals most specifically with building psionic control to the point of illusion casting, astral projection, mental construct conjuration and psychic battling.

The other a physical-based martial art that teaches strikes, forms and counters, but **also** develops control the *brain* itself to push the practitioner into a Theta Wave state where they are open to instantaneous reaction, intuition, instinct and can even control their autonomic system.

[image: meme describing Superman's fighting abilities]

I've not been able to find a lot of instances of their combat applied use, though; was wondering if anyone had further information?

Are there any scans showing the forms being used in combat?

Comment: Torqasm-Vo is basically yoga; https://kryptonculture.tumblr.com/post/50702768265/torquasm-vo Meditation and mental strength training.

Comment: Torqasm-Rao is analogous to Tai-Chi; https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-8f00d580d1fcccdebac8c1ed2395d4c0

Comment: @Valorum Any idea what form of Tai Chi? Yang [physical development] or Chen [combat oriented]?

Comment: it's definitely a martial art that is intended to be used against opponents